# How do I temporarily mask touchscreen touches events in C on Linux?

Tags: c, mask, capture, touchscreen

I've written a program in C that activates commands when the user flicks from the edges of the screen. For instance, flicking upward from the bottom edge brings up the keyboard. This portion of my code is working fine.

The issue I am having is that the very making of the flicking motion also interrupts applications, as one's fingers need to drag across some of the screen to activate the trigger. I don't want this action to affect apps that are on screen while the user flicks the screen edge.

I would like to add some C code that will temporarily mask touch events. I can handle the code that activates the masking properly (such as events which originate from the edges of the screen) and when to unmask.

I can handle all of the above with exception to the code that does the masking and unmask of the touch events. I am not asking for a full complete code but just a pointer in the right direction. I would like to know what library to use and the appropriate command which does the masking.

I'll not post the code as it is a couple hundred lines long and would surely lead to straying from the question; the code works fine, aside from the issue above.

I am on a Raspberry Pi 3b+ with Rasbian OS and an Official Raspberry Pi 7" touch screen. The main C libraries which I am using for the program are linux/input.h and X11/extensions/XTest.h.

I will supply any additional info if asked.

*** EDIT ***

Finally figured it out! The biggest issue what finding what to search for...

I masked the pointer/touch events with the following command:

```
XGrabPointer(dpy, root, False, PointerMotionMask, GrabModeSync, GrabModeAsync, None, None, CurrentTime);
```

In the code above, the touch motion is masked (PointerMotionMask), the pointer/touch for windows is masked (GrabModeSync), and the keyboard key events are not masked (GrabModeAsync).

To unmask, I used these commands:

```
        XQueryPointer(dpy, RootWindow (dpy, 0),
         &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window,
         &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root,
         &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y,
         &event.xbutton.state);

        usleep(10000);

        XUngrabPointer(dpy, CurrentTime);

        usleep(10000);

        XQueryPointer(dpy, RootWindow (dpy, 0),
         &event.xbutton.root, &event.xbutton.window,
         &event.xbutton.x_root, &event.xbutton.y_root,
         &event.xbutton.x, &event.xbutton.y,
         &event.xbutton.state);
```

I'm still learning Xlib, so I don't entirely know why one needs to add usleep and XQueryPointer, but I found that it's needed or the program is unpredictable. I merely copied this type of code from my buttonPress() function. I couldn't find any complete, simple, and clear answer, so a lot of try/fail was required on this one.

Now, I am able to swipe from the edges on my Raspberry Pi touchscreen, and there is no interruption to the currently active window.

If anyone wants to see the code, just ask and I'll post it in full. And if anyone knows how this code works and why I need to add usleep and XQueryPointer, I'd like to hear.

Sources used:
[X11: will XGrabPointer prevent other apps from any mouse event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122360/x11-will-xgrabpointer-prevent-other-apps-from-any-mouse-event)
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/pointer-grabbing.html